# How to clone an object in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I have few Questions. All related to cloning an object in Parse.com.

1. Is there a way to use jQuery in parse.com? because then I can use the `extend` method. I tried to use `$.extend({}, object1, object2)` but parse.com doesn't seem to recognize $ or jquery.
2. I have a `request` object which I need to clone and another `UserInfoList` object which I need to clone ?

One way is that I clone them manually and insert each field in the new object. Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: I assume you are doing this in Cloud Code?

Comment: Yes I am doing it in cloud code. I ended up creating a deep copy manually.

Answer (score 2):

From the Parse.Object Documentation you can [object2 = object1.clone()](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#clone)

Comment: `object.clone();` is not working on User defined object types I ended up doing something similar to mentioned [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/make-a-copy-of-a-pfobject) and create a deep copy.